# lie algebra associated to a profinite group

Tags: ct.category-theory, lie-algebras, profinite-groups

is there a natural way to associate a Lie algebra (over real numbers or other field) to a profinite group in a functorial way ? 
I.e. I'm looking for a functor $L: \mathbf{ProfinGroups}\rightarrow \mathbf{LieAlg}$

If such functor exists, could we have a fully faithful functor if we restrict $L$ to some full subcategory of $\mathbf{ProfinGroups}$ ?

Comment: Can you do that for a finite group?

Comment: @DenisNardin that is  part of the question!

Comment: Yes there exists a functor. You need some further conditions to make the question nontrivial.

Comment: @YCor I'm looking for those conditions! I'm in learning stage. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Read Serre's book "Lie groups and Lie algebras" to see what is done for $p$-adic Lie groups (which are a special class of profinite groups near the identity); this will also make clearer the variant one should consider in place of full faithfulness given that connectedness is not available.

Comment: Maclev construction?

Comment: @nfdc23 it seams you know the answer! it will be nice if write down the details...

Comment: Serre wrote down the details; please look at his book.  You don't say anything about your specific motivation (presumably this is not just idle curiosity), so there's nothing more for me to say.